# How to get a post back parameter value in code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am triggering a postback event in aspx page as below:

```
__doPostBack('AddNewEmployeeType', "empl", "sick");
```

Code behind:

```
string val = Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
```

By the above code i was able to get only one first value, but my intention is to get all three parameter values. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

Use the `__EVENTARGUMENT`:

```
string parameter = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]; 
string val = Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET"); // AddNewEmployeeType
```

[Here's a tutorial: Understanding the JavaScript __doPostBack Function](http://aspalliance.com/895_Understanding_the_JavaScript___doPostBack_Function.5)

If you need to pass multiple parameters back to codebehind you need to split it by a delimiter yourself. You could for example use the pipe `|`:

```
__doPostBack('AddNewEmployeeType', "empl|sick");
```

and in codebehind:

```
string parameter = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]; 
string[] allParams = parameter.Split('|');
```

Comment: Still I was able to get only one parameter. Problem not resolved.

Comment: Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] is coming as "undefined"

Comment: When the `__doPostBack` function is called with only one argument, the value in `__EVENTARGUMENT` can be something like “undefined”. This depends on the browser. I recommend to send an empty string as second argument when no data is required for the request.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to __doPostBack is technically incorrect. If you check the source of an ASP.NET page, you'll see the function:

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
```

Note it has only 2 parameters. If you need to pass more values, you need to stuff them into the eventArgument parameter.

How you do this is up to you - use a comma-separated list, or JSON, or whatever suits you, and parse this value (by accessing `Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]`) on the server.

Answer (score 0):

### Alternatives

Postbacks are not supposed to be handled like that. If a control is raising postbacks, and if it's an User Control, it should implement `IPostBackDataHandler`. and you should assign an `EventHandler` to it, even if it's a custom one.

---

### References

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackdatahandler(v=vs.110).aspx