# Webforms postback with multiple arguments

Tags: asp.net, webforms, postback, dopostback

I wish to call the `__doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument)` function. In the code file I would then read the arguments as usual like this: `Dim param As String = Request("__EVENTARGUMENT")`. However this doesn't work for multiple arguments.

Someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20187830/how-to-get-a-post-back-parameter-value-in-code-behind) suggested that you could use a json or csv-list. Usually I would just choose a delimiter that sepeates my arguments. However in my case now the argument may contain any character, so I can't just decide on any delimiter, so I figured I'd use a JSON.

I tried this.

Markup:

```
<button type="button" id="btn_postbackButton" onclick="__doPostBack('btn_postbackButton', {one: 'someText', two: 'moreText'});">TestButton</button>
```

Code-File

```
If (IsPostBack) Then
    Dim tgt As Object = Request("__EVENTTARGET")
    Dim param As Object = Request("__EVENTARGUMENT") ' what datatype to use?
    ' [...]
    ' how to get arguments from json?
End If
```

Now how do I get my arguments back in the code? What datatype do I use for the parameters? Calling `param.ToString()` only returns `[object Object]`

What's more, the arguments are generated in the code file in my actual application, and there may be different ones and some may be missing, using a simple array doesn't work for me as you can't determine after the fact which array position coresponds to which argument. And regardless it still gives me `[object Object]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your button is clicked, the page sends the following HTML form fields:

```html
__EVENTTARGET: btn_postbackButton
__EVENTARGUMENT: [object Object]
```

To get your json on the server side as a string, use the following button markup:

```html
<button type="button" id="btn_postbackButton" onclick="__doPostBack('btn_postbackButton', '{one: \'someText\', two: \'moreText\'}');">TestButton</button>
```